# Remove duplication on the plot, matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the following data and I would like to plot them on a 3D figure. One of the columns has a duplicate values, is there a way to plot them without the duplication.

```
YParetoFront XParetoFront ZParetoFront
389831.0625 1001258368  184836.875
388580.5625 1000080960  184836.875
295196.1563 998143872   185846.1094
294647.1563 998014144   185846.2188
297674.7188 997732352   184836.875
364729.0313 997628608   184836.875
299553.9688 997584128   184836.875
452488  996902400   184836.875

Z           Y       X
209543.6094 337821  816632768
210823.6563 280745.75   834212224
211740.2969 306142.4688 838344256
212585.9688 241426.1875 842831296
212755.4531 263043.2188 853012992
210407.7344 294499.5    859938944
209652.9844 202001  867667648
209791.9844 295622.0938 867938496
207461.7656 115891.1016 870347328
210851.5781 317453.8438 873238912
210841  280895.4688 875502144
200773.0781 232767.0938 875935616


scatter3(Y, Z, X,'s','filled')
hold on
scatter3(YParetoFront, ZParetoFront, XParetoFront,'filled')
% indices to unique values in column 3
[~, ind] = unique(ZParetoFront(:, 3), 'rows');
% duplicate indices
duplicate_ind = setdiff(1:size(ZParetoFront, 3), ind);
% duplicate values
duplicate_value = ZParetoFront(duplicate_ind, 3);
legend('Remainder', 'Pareto Front')
xlabel('Y')
ylabel('Z')
zlabel('X')
rotate3d on;
```

Comment: Assuming you'd have to remove the data you don't want from the vector before plotting - are you having a problem keeping unique values, or you know how to do that, and your problem is in fact the _plotting_ aspect?

Comment: The problem is I have around 350 points, and when I remove them manually it destroys the shape. I added the three lines of the indices to the code, but it doesnt remove the duplication

Comment: You can check, the code is working for plotting but not removing the duplication

Comment: As a general rule, you can put `NaN` in at least one of the coordinates of a point to stop it from being plotted. See if this works for you...